# Java Job Failed to Connect to Standalone Local Master

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am new to spark and have been trying to run my first java spark job through a standalone local master.
Now my master is up and one worker gets registered as well, but when run below spark program I got org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult.
My program should work as it runs fine when master is set to local.

My Spark Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Setup configuration
    String appName = "My Very First Spark Job";
    //String sparkMaster = "local[2]";
    String sparkMaster = "spark://10.0.0.116:7077";

    JavaSparkContext spContext = null;

    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
            .setAppName(appName)
            .setMaster(sparkMaster);

    //Create Spark Context from configuration
    spContext = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
```

Logs:

```
    17/11/28 21:22:23 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://10.0.0.116:7077...
    17/11/28 21:22:23 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /10.0.0.116:7077 after 30 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
    17/11/28 21:22:23 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master 10.0.0.116:7077
    org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.apply(PartialFunction.scala:167)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anonfun$tryRegisterAllMasters$1$$anon$1.run(StandaloneAppClient.scala:109)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:609)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.RequestMessage$.readRpcAddress(NettyRpcEnv.scala:582)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.RequestMessage$.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:592)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.internalReceive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:651)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.receive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:636)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processRpcRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:157)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:105)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead(TransportChannelHandler.java:118)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
        at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:643)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.handle(TransportResponseHandler.java:190)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:121)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        ... 1 more
```

Spark Master:

```
    Jings-MBP-6:bin jingzhou$ ./spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
    Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
    17/11/28 20:55:11 INFO Master: Started daemon with process name: 12707@Jings-MBP-6.gateway
    17/11/28 20:55:11 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM
    17/11/28 20:55:11 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP
    17/11/28 20:55:11 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT
    17/11/28 20:55:11 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    17/11/28 20:55:11 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: jingzhou
    17/11/28 20:55:11 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: jingzhou
    17/11/28 20:55:11 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
    17/11/28 20:55:11 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
    17/11/28 20:55:11 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(jingzhou); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(jingzhou); groups with modify permissions: Set()
    17/11/28 20:55:12 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkMaster' on port 7077.
    17/11/28 20:55:12 INFO Master: Starting Spark master at spark://10.0.0.116:7077
    17/11/28 20:55:12 INFO Master: Running Spark version 2.2.0
    17/11/28 20:55:12 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'MasterUI' on port 8080.
    17/11/28 20:55:12 INFO MasterWebUI: Bound MasterWebUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://10.0.0.116:8080
    17/11/28 20:55:12 INFO Utils: Successfully started service on port 6066.
    17/11/28 20:55:12 INFO StandaloneRestServer: Started REST server for submitting applications on port 6066
    17/11/28 20:55:12 INFO Master: I have been elected leader! New state: ALIVE
    17/11/28 20:59:27 INFO Master: Registering worker 10.0.0.116:64461 with 8 cores, 15.0 GB RAM
    17/11/28 21:03:42 ERROR TransportRequestHandler: Error while invoking RpcHandler#receive() on RPC id 4722074090999773956
    java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:609)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.RequestMessage$.readRpcAddress(NettyRpcEnv.scala:582)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.RequestMessage$.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:592)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.internalReceive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:651)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.receive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:636)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processRpcRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:157)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:105)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead(TransportChannelHandler.java:118)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
        at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:643)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Spark Worker:

```
    Jings-MBP-6:bin jingzhou$ ./spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://10.0.0.116:7077
    Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
    17/11/28 20:59:26 INFO Worker: Started daemon with process name: 12794@Jings-MBP-6.gateway
    17/11/28 20:59:26 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM
    17/11/28 20:59:26 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP
    17/11/28 20:59:26 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT
    17/11/28 20:59:26 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    17/11/28 20:59:26 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: jingzhou
    17/11/28 20:59:26 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: jingzhou
    17/11/28 20:59:26 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
    17/11/28 20:59:26 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
    17/11/28 20:59:26 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(jingzhou); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(jingzhou); groups with modify permissions: Set()
    17/11/28 20:59:27 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkWorker' on port 64461.
    17/11/28 20:59:27 INFO Worker: Starting Spark worker 10.0.0.116:64461 with 8 cores, 15.0 GB RAM
    17/11/28 20:59:27 INFO Worker: Running Spark version 2.2.0
    17/11/28 20:59:27 INFO Worker: Spark home: /Users/jingzhou/Desktop/hadoop/spark/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7
    17/11/28 20:59:27 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'WorkerUI' on port 8081.
    17/11/28 20:59:27 INFO WorkerWebUI: Bound WorkerWebUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://10.0.0.116:8081
    17/11/28 20:59:27 INFO Worker: Connecting to master 10.0.0.116:7077...
    17/11/28 20:59:27 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /10.0.0.116:7077 after 26 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
    17/11/28 20:59:27 INFO Worker: Successfully registered with master spark://10.0.0.116:7077
```

Comment: which spark version are you using?

Comment: Could this be the answer to your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126186/spark-standalone-transportrequesthandler-error-while-invoking-rpchandler-whe

Comment: Could be you are using different Spark binaries for the master and your client. Have you checked those are the same on both sides?

Comment: Master version: Spark 2.2.0 built for Hadoop 2.7.3 Client: 2.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem when trying to connect to the local cluster from my eclipse dev environment.

In my case it was version mismatch with master and with my development environment, where I was using maven dependencies.

Cluster was : 2.2.1
My dev was :  2.1.0

Once I corrected the version, error was resolved.